# Shortcode to generate and save password in a file

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

I have the following shortcode:

```
// Add Shortcode
function custom_shortcode_phptest() {

  function generatePassword($length = 6) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$pass = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
$pass .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
return $pass;
}

$password = generatePassword();

$data = time();

$test = '/home/blablabla/public_html/ot/docs/test/' . $password . '.txt';
$file = fopen($test,"w");
fwrite($file,$data);
fclose($file);
echo 'Your pass is ' . $password . ' and it is valid for 3 days.';

}
add_shortcode( 'phptest', 'custom_shortcode_phptest' );
```

It will generate a password and save it in a file. But when I use [phptest] shortcode in email, sent from Wordpress admin panel it doesn't work. Is it okay to use function inside function in php shortcode?

Comment: have you tried to `return` rather than to `echo` the message?

Comment: Yeee, you saved me! Please make it an answer so I can mark it answered :))

Comment: @File_Submit Posted the updated code for anyone else who may run into a similar issue. You can click the checkbox next to the answer to set your question as resolved.

Comment: Storing passwords as file names under public html? That's sounds rather unsecure, specifically if the directory listings is enabled by change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comment under the OP's question, below is the solution by using a `return` instead of an `echo`:

```
add_shortcode( 'phptest', 'custom_shortcode_phptest' );
function custom_shortcode_phptest() { // Add Shortcode

    function generatePassword( $length = 6 ) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen( $characters );
        $pass = '';
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
            $pass .= $characters[rand( 0, $charactersLength - 1 )];
        }
        return $pass;
    }

    $password = generatePassword();

    $data = time();

    $test = '/home/blablabla/public_html/ot/docs/test/' . $password . '.txt';
    $file = fopen( $test, "w" );
    fwrite( $file, $data );
    fclose( $file );
    return 'Your pass is ' . $password . ' and it is valid for 3 days.';
}
```